# FlatList onendreached triggers indefinitely

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My FlatList triggers onendreached not as expected. onEndReached gets called again and again. I have read some suggestion to wrap flatlist in a view with flex:1 but I still doesn't work properly. Also removing the scrollView didn't work-

This didn't help https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1736#issuecomment-401815949

```
<View style={baseStyles.body}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:"row", backgroundColor:theme.button.tertiary}}>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <SearchBar
                onChangeText={(query) => this.setState({query})}
                placeholder='Hier suchen...' 
                showLoading
            />
        </View>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'column'}}> 
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <FlatList
                data={articlesData}
                renderItem={renderFunction}
                onEndReached={this._onEndReached}
                onEndThreshold={0}
                refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
                onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
                keyExtractor={item => item.slug}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{marginBottom:10}}>
                <Text style={{color:this.state.theme.text.primary,textAlign:"center",fontSize:16}}>Gefunden: {rowCount}</Text>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Your `onEndThreshold` is 0 try setting it to a larger number like 0.5

Comment: @Andrew didn't help

Comment: Couple suggestions. Duplicate this issue using the minimum number of elements. IOW, simplify the code as much as possible, removing anything not key to duplicating this issue. This may give you some insight. If you still see the problem, then create a demon on https://snack.expo.io/ that we can play with to help troubleshoot. And if all else fails, maybe debounce is a solution you can live with

Comment: this is due to number of row are visible to screen and no scroll needed

Comment: @Chris ty, I will try that today

Comment: @Jigar nope, the list starts empty that might invoke onEndReached but after that 10 entries are added each time as long as the API returns entries (currently there are 25 entries all get load after onEndReached triggers which it does indefinitely, which is not the point of infit scrolling)

Comment: @ChrisGeirman I reduced it down to just the FlatList as a screen of the navigation tab. Still doesn't work properly.

Comment: @freddy did you create a snack?

Comment: @Chris no I didn't. I have change the way the flatloet refreshes. So now it onEndReached still doesn't work as intended but the user doesn't notice that the list is already loading more items.

Answer (score 0):

If it is loading or error you can try to use `onEndReached={this.state.isLoading ? () => {} : this._onEndReached}`; just let onEndReached do nothing when the state is loading. I've tried serveral way (debounce, await setState, using flag) but only this way work as expected.

```
<View style={baseStyles.body}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:"row", backgroundColor:theme.button.tertiary}}>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <SearchBar
                onChangeText={(query) => this.setState({query})}
                placeholder='Hier suchen...' 
                showLoading
            />
        </View>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'column'}}> 
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <FlatList
                data={articlesData}
                renderItem={renderFunction}
                onEndReached={this.state.isLoading ? () => {} : this._onEndReached}
                onEndThreshold={0}
                refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
                onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
                keyExtractor={item => item.slug}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{marginBottom:10}}>
                <Text style={{color:this.state.theme.text.primary,textAlign:"center",fontSize:16}}>Gefunden: {rowCount}</Text>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
</View>
```